# Как поставить другую версию Python на Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, sublime-text, установка

У меня сейчас стоит Python 3.8, мне её надо поменять на Python 3.11. Как это сделать?

Comment: а устанавливать питон нужной версии не пробовали?

Comment: Она уже установлена